# Tomcat and Eclipse Galileo

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am using Eclipse Galileo....I am not able to find the server option in it. How do I the run the tomcat server from eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat Server connector is bundled with Eclipse Galileo. 
Just opening server view up. Click file menu Window -> Show View -> Other... search for "Server" in pop up and select Servers. Server view then open up.